# X11 lets me change to other resolutions, but only the first time the system starts

Tags: xorg, wine, display, display-resolution

I use Wine 1.8. The first (and sometimes second, rarely third) time I run my game: it switches between resolutions with no problem

After that, it fails. Running wine from the console shows that it could not tell X11 to switch to that resolution.

`xrandr` confirms this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1280x720      59.86  
   1152x768      59.78  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   848x480       59.66  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.38  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

After, when it fails:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Why do the resolutions disappear? It's not that my display can't handle this, because it works the first, second, and sometimes third times.

**EDIT:** Kernel driver is `radeon`, GPU is `AMD Radeon 6310 (Lenovo Wrestler)`